# How to access controller instance inside the RSpec integration test using Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, capybara, rspec-rails, rspec2

I am building an engine for Rails 3.1 and so far it's fine.

But I am trying to make the configuration of the engine much more generic through the configuration.

e.g. The main app has to write the method using a symbol.

```
# app/config/initializers/my_engine.rb
MyEngine::Engine.login_url = :sign_in_url
```

And to test it via Rpec, I'm writing a RSpec integration spec.

```
...
page.current_url.should eql(send(MyEngine::Engine.login_url))
```

And the above fails saying `NoMethod error...`
Actually I want to call that `send(...)` on the controller instance of the main app.

A couple of weeks ago, with Rails3.1.rc..., it was passing, but now it's failing.

So. the question is: how can I call that method on the controller instance in an RSpec/Capybara integration spec? Or am I doing it the wrong way?